# Ubuntu is opening in a black screen

Tags: boot, screen

Yesterday mi wife did an update and halfway the update she closed the computer. When starting up again, the screen remains black with only a "-" in the left top corner. However, if i start in recovery mode, the screen comes on normally.

Ubuntu is installed on an acer aspire 7520
I see also: Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-194-generic

Then i start in recovery mode, and used all the tools that are available for eventual recovery namely: clean, dpkg, fsck, grub and network,
Wat can I do?
Do you need more information?
Thanks,
PS, I am not very good on computer.

Comment: A version of Ubuntu might help. That is a kernel version you have given not the OS. The update "might" have been a new kernel mine did a kernel update in last day or two. If you can get to the Grub menu you can choose advanced options and try and load a slightly older kernel.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: How can i get to the grub menu?

Comment: If it is not dual boot you can still access the Grub menu by pressing shift as it is starting up the OS. You may have to try more then once to hit the right spot in the startup.

Comment: I did start with the Shift key en used : Linux 4.15.0-188-generic in stead of Linux 4.15.0-194-genericand. That worked. How can I make it start in Linux 4.15.0-188-generic from scratch?

Comment: This site will give the step by step. Ignore the first step as you already have the kernel that works on the disk. https://gist.github.com/chaiyujin/c08e59752c3e238ff3b1a5098322b363

Comment: @David - I think that’s worthy of an upvote if you want to post as an answer.

Comment: @Will was thinking same thing

Comment: @Will done and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After finding that your Ubuntu machine will work better after changing the active kernel you may want to make that the default kernel.

Follow these steps. I have also included a web site for reference.

Install the default kernel:

sudo apt install @the kernel you want@

Set GRUB Default Kernel

Find entrance from /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Get the $menuentry_id_option:
grep submenu /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Example output:

submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf' {
'gnulinux-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf' is what we need.
Get the specific kernel option:
grep gnulinux-4.15.0 /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Example output:

menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-126-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-126-generic-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf' {
'gnulinux-4.15.0-126-generic-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf' is what we need.

Set GRUB_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub
Join two entry strings obtained above by '>', set to GRUB_DEFAULT.
GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf>gnulinux-4.15.0-126-generic-advanced-4591a659-55e2-4bec-8dbe-d98bd9e489cf'

Update grub
sudo update-grub

Reboot the machine

web link for reference. https://gist.github.com/chaiyujin/c08e59752c3e238ff3b1a5098322b363

Comment: Dear All, Thank you for all the help. with reading al the help notes, i found wat to do.

Comment: If the answer helped please accept the answer.